# Use values from MySQL in custom plugin - Nutch

Tags: mysql, nutch

I'm using Apache Nutch 1.12. I have configured it with ElasticSearch and created a parse filter plugin based on my need. Currently, I'm reading some values that are needed for the filter plugin from a properties file. But, I need to read it from MySQL database. I've searched for integrating Nutch with MySQL. But, I found results only to configure MySQL to store crawled data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your plugin code, you can use regular jdbc to pull out those values, right?

Comment: But, it create a new connection every time when I use that plugin. I need to configure nutch with MySQL.